# LED pod light orange wire connector?

Tags: wiring

I have 30 X LED ceiling pod lights (with orange wire connectors). Lights have small spring clips to hold it to the sheet rock. Do not need the cans, as they will not fit in ceiling (it is close to the eaves). But lamp wires will not reach my j-box.

I purchased some insulated pvc casing wire to extend the lamp wire to the j-box. I cut off the orange connector on the lamp. I skinned all 4 wires (2 from extension, 2 from lamp in a staggered pattern so the white splice and the black splice were not side by side). Twisted 2 whites, soldered, shrink wrapped. Then twisted 2 blacks, soldered, shrink wrapped. Then shrink wrapped "all" the wires with a little larger shrink wrap. Lamp now has a extension wire long enough to reach my j-box. It now looks like it has no splice, and no short orange connector, is smooth and tight. Will this meet NEC? Not trying to hide anything, but you cannot tell the wire coming off lamp has a splice under all the shrink wrap!

Comment: Congratulations. If you modified all 30 fixtures, you now have 30 pieces of unusable junk.

Answer (score 2):

If the light is designed (and listed) for use in a can fixture, that's how it must be used (which is what this sounds like - retrofit "pods" with the connectors on short wires because they expect to be inside cans and don't need long wires.

There are canless LED "pucks" made, they are designed (and listed) for use without cans.

**You** modifying one type to try and do the job of another is not covered in the UL listing for the one type. So you now have *user-modified unlisted devices*, which **should** fail inspection unless you manage to fool the inspector, and **will** be discovered by fire investigators in the event of a problem, causing your insurance to laugh all the way to the bank while not paying you for the fire damage you caused by modifying fixtures. Soldered joints are pretty much not allowed in modern house wiring (I think the very specific procedures used to work on ancient knob-and-tube wiring are still in there, but hardly ever used in practice since it mostly gets removed, these days.) They will be evident to the fire investigators after the fact.